# Stay or leave if another position offered

Tags: job-offer, career-development

Hello Im currently working as a web developer and Im hired to build 1 project, I was offered another position inside the company to work as an infrastructure coordinator, I really hate that part of technology as it is pretty much networks, servers, monitoring, service desk and solving  very non-exciting issues like in software development.

My boss already told me that he was going to lookup to get me into another project but before that he asked me if I wanted to go to that area, told him I was not interested as I was in software development and that if there was no more projects I’ll just leave to another place.

Im hired by an outsource and getting that job in that area would get me hired by the actual company Im doing the project for, salary would be kinda the same but with more legal benefits, outsource told me that when the project was done I would be available to join another projects if any are available.

Im considering leaving both parties and lookup for a fresh start in a new place as I don’t feel safe in that company anymore, should I stay in the infrastructure department or start looking at job proposals?

Update: Rejected the infrastructure proposal since it's way way below my salary expectation, I get 3 times more being a developer, I'll just hit hard the code and move on to another place if there's no more projects, thanks for the advice to everyone

Comment: Welcome to this community. Please improve the clarity of your text by adding appropriate punctuation and checking the spelling in the first place. This will help your community fellows speed-read your text and yourself get thoughtful answers.

Comment: After you completed the project you have been offered a position as employee (for a currently open job), why you do not feel "safe"? To refuse is perfectly fine (and maybe not unexpected) but...why should you jump out of both boats?

Comment: Seems like a lot of people in the company joined for x reason and they ended up in different fields that are not related to their field, the guy that Ill be working with in the infrastructure department is a guy from marketing, I dont feel safe anymore because I was invited to join that department and because my boss stated that he was going to possibly get me into another project, so I can assume that there’s currently no more projects available for me right now, I want to keep developing Software as it is my passion and I find myself in peace with that duty

Comment: However I havent finished university and it gets really hard to land a job without the damned papers that say that I know stuff, thats why Im struggling into deciding to stay even if I hate being on a servicedesk or just start looking up for more jobs even if my boss find me a new project, which imo its not gonna happen, so yeah pretty much this is the issue, struggle to find a new job or stay safe even if I hate my job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of observations about your situation.

- "Infrastructure coordinator" can also mean Dev Ops. That field has plenty of software engineering involved with it. And, it's a fabulous opportunity to learn about how things really work, both in software and in your company. With respect, your dislike of it may be unjustified.
- Dev Ops people are in strong demand.
- It sounds like your boss has your back career-development-wise. He's looking to keep you, and looking to find a project that uses your skills. That's a pretty significant show of support for you.
- Being offered a full-time job is a very good thing, especially if you're fresh out of school.
- You can look for another job, but don't turn this one down just yet. It's always good to have more than one offer to choose from if you can. And it's easier to find work when you're already employed.

I hope, at this stage of your career, you'll focus on learning as much as you can as fast as you can.

Comment: I was worried about an answer like this, thanks and well I think Im gonna think about it a little bit more, immature decisions lead to terrible places

Answer (score 1):

Don't leave a job unless you've got something better to go to. (some jobs are so bad that being unemployed may be better, but this doesn't apply to you)

Tell your boss that you would be happy to accept his offer, and would like more development if it becomes available but in the meantime you're interested in learning any aspect of the industry that you can.

If you don't enjoy it, start looking for the job you really want. If no one will employ you until you finish university, then just wait until you do, it'll come soon enough.

Comment: I don't plan to finish university, would absorb a lot of time and money. I know the path I need to walk in order to become a successful person, this might sound really arrogant but knowledge is available in so many ways these days that going to a school, in my country, is just for the people that don't have a path, I do, I'm walking it. I'll stay as much as I can in this job because my boss is an awesome leader and mentor, learning from his as much as possible is my shortcut goal until I feel more capable of going into the interview hell again

Comment: You're right; a couple of years experience of actually doing a job is worth a lot more than a degree, which just helps you get your first job. As you've already got that job, you don't need the degree.